# How to get the Expense id and passing it to Django view function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm struggling with finding the correct way to pass {{expense.id}} to a view function inside Django so that based on the id, I can update the expense detail.
Expenses are coming from a model which relates by 'ForeignKey' to the Projects coming from another Model. I need the expense ID before submitting another form which take cares of updating that transaction.

[image: Html Table that I want to Update]

view.py

```
def updateTransaction(request, project_slug):
    id: ?
```

form.py

```
class ExpenseForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField()
   deposit = forms.IntegerField()
   witdraw = forms.IntegerField()
```

model.py

```
class Expense(models.Model):
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expenses')
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   deposit = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True)
   witdraw = models.IntegerField(default = 0, null = True)
   created_at = jmodels.jDateField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_list, name='list'),
    path('add', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('export_pdf', views.export_pdf, name='export_pdf'),
    path('login', views.userPage, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logoutUser , name='logout'),
    path('depts', views.depts, name='depts'),
    path('<slug:project_slug>', views.project_detail, name='detail'),
    path('update/<slug:project_slug>', views.updateTransaction, name='update'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('update/<id>/', views.update_transaction, name='update_transaction'),
]
```

template.html

```
<table>
    <th>...</th>
    {% for expense in expenses %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'update_transaction' expense.id  %}"> Update </a>   
            </td>
            ...
            ...
        </tr>
    {% endfor%}
</table>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Expense, etc.


def update_transation(request, id):
    expense = get_object_or_404(Expense, id=id)
    project = expense.project
    expense_id = expense.id
    etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this . I hope this will work.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work since I want this id in my view function.